# qt: I would like to disable the key bindings automatically set for a QTreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, key-bindings, qtreeview

I am using PyQt4 and a QTreeView (although this could just as easily apply to qt directly).

Right now there are default key bindings that control the expanding/collapsing of branches using the right and left arrows. Unfortunately, these bindings are not ideal and I would like to disable them.  I have not been able to figure out how to do that.  Does anyone know how to disable (or reassign) the default key bindings on a QTreeView?

Comment: What are those keys ? The arrows or... ?

Comment: Yes, the arrows are problematic because I want to navigate with them, but they keep expanding or collapsing rows (quite unexpectedly) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible options for you:
1) Reimplement the [keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtreeview.html#keyPressEvent) of QTreeView and check if the key pressed are either [Qt::Key_Up](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#Key-enum) or [Qt::Key_Down](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#Key-enum).

2) You could install an [eventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#eventFilter) and check if the event is a [QEvent::KeyPress](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qevent.html#Type-enum) and that the key matches either [Qt::Key_Up](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#Key-enum) or [Qt::Key_Down](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#Key-enum).

I don't know PyQt so I can't give you code in Python, but I hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: That seems pretty clear, thanks.  So once I re-implement the keyPressEvent (something I am planning on doing anyway because I want to change some other behavior) I will have to manually move the selection, right?

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, but could you point me to the correct way to manually move the selection? I am in the keyPressEvent of the QTreeView and am successfully intercepting the left arrow keypress. I have successfully built a new QModelIndex that refers to the correct cell, but I can't figure out how to get the QTreeView to actually use this QModelIndex to select the appropriate cell.

Comment: Of course, once I ask a question I manage to figure it out: Use the selectionModel of the QTreeView.  So I use the following lines: newModelIndex = self.model().index(row, col, parent)   self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(newModelIndex, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.SelectCurrent)